# In python/tkinter, is it possible to change a access db result name before it hits in insert in treeview?

Tags: python, ms-access, tkinter, treeview

I am using python/tkinter.  I am connected to a mdb and querying it for employees where one column(supervisor) is checked or unchecked depending on if they are one.  Checked = Yes is a supervisor, unchecked is No, not a supervisor.  In my treeview insert for this, checked appears as 'True', unchecked appears as 'False'.  I would ideally want True to be 'Y' and False to be 'N'.  Is this possible?  I have tried many things like if else, changing the query to the mdb, and others with no luck.  Any and all suggestions greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Code snippet below:

```
#CONNECT TO MDB CASHIERS
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=<pathway removed>;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()    
    
    cashiers = cursor.execute("SELECT * from users WHERE active ORDER BY fullname")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    
    conn.commit()
    
    conn.close()
    
    style = ttk.Style()

    style.theme_use('default')

    style.configure("Treeview",
        background='lightblue',
        foreground='black',
        rowheight=30,
        fieldbackground='#b568d9')
    
    style.map('Treeview',
        background=[('selected', "#347083")])
    
    tree_frame = Frame(casrwin)
    tree_frame.pack(pady=10)

    tree_scroll = Scrollbar(tree_frame)
    tree_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    my_tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set, selectmode="extended")
    my_tree.pack()

    tree_scroll.config(command=my_tree.yview)

#COLUMNHEADINGS
    my_tree['columns'] = ("User", "Full Name", "Location", "Drawer 1", "Drawer 2", "Drawer 3", "Supervisor")

    my_tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
    my_tree.column("User", anchor=W, width=140)
    my_tree.column("Full Name", anchor=W, width=140)
    my_tree.column("Location", anchor=W, width=175)
    my_tree.column("Drawer 1", anchor=W, width=140)
    my_tree.column("Drawer 2", anchor=W, width=140)
    my_tree.column("Drawer 3", anchor=W, width=140)
    my_tree.column("Supervisor", anchor=W, width=140)

    my_tree.heading("#0", text="", anchor=W)
    my_tree.heading("User", text="User", anchor=W)
    my_tree.heading("Full Name", text="Full Name", anchor=W)
    my_tree.heading("Location", text="Location", anchor=W)
    my_tree.heading("Drawer 1", text="Drawer 1", anchor=W)
    my_tree.heading("Drawer 2", text="Drawer 2", anchor=W)
    my_tree.heading("Drawer 3", text="Drawer 3", anchor=W)
    my_tree.heading("Supervisor", text="Supervisor", anchor=W)


    my_tree.tag_configure('blue', background="lightblue")
    my_tree.tag_configure('normal', background="white")

    my_tag='normal'

#ADD DATA TO SCREEN
    for record in data:
        my_tag='gray' if my_tag=='normal' else 'normal'
        my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=record[0], text='', values=(record[0], record[3], record[1], record[9], record[10], record[11], record[5], record[4], record[6], record[7], record[8]), tags=(my_tag))
```

I tried if else, changing mdb query, all in many different places and iterations without success.

Comment: Post what you have tried on using *if / else*.  Also what are the values for `Supervisor` column in the database table?

Comment: Thank you for writing acw1668.  The values were True if checked, False if not.  I tried Agent P's suggestion, and it got me where I needed.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display 'Y' for True and 'N' for False in your Treeview column for supervisors, you can modify the data you're inserting into the Treeview. You can use a conditional statement to convert True to 'Y' and False to 'N' before inserting it into the Treeview.

To do that, change the last part of the code which says `# ADD DATA TO SCREEN` to the code below.

```
# ADD DATA TO SCREEN
for record in data:
    my_tag = 'gray' if my_tag == 'normal' else 'normal'
    supervisor_value = 'Y' if record[5] else 'N'  # Convert True to 'Y' and False to 'N'
    my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=record[0], text='', values=(record[0], record[3], record[1], record[9], record[10], record[11], supervisor_value, record[4], record[6], record[7], record[8]), tags=(my_tag))
```

Comment: Awesome!!  That worked beautifully!!  Thank you soso much!!

Comment: Done!  It will show after I get my 15 respect I believe, but definitely upped it :)